# Aurelia HttpClient with Authentication

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to use the Aurelia HttpClient to call the TagniFi API on a different domain (and authenticating).  The relevant code is:

```
return this._httpClient.createRequest(uri)
     .asGet()
     .withCredentials(true)
     .withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'localhost:9000')
     .withHeader('Authorization', 'Basic <my-key>')
     .send();
```

I do receive a status 200 from the API, but I get the following error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: A >wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header >when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is >therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest >is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I am not sure if this is a error in the way I am making the call or a bug in Aurelia.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** is an header sent in the response by the server and in your case you use it in the request from the client.

It's not a bug in Aurelia but a misuse of CORS.

See [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636765) for more information on CORS.

Comment: Thanks Valentin,  I appreciate your response.  So, if I am understanding correctly, the issues is that the destination server that I am calling is not configured to return the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.  In other words, this isn't a bug in my code but an error in the configuration on the server?  If it is an error in my code, please let me know if you have a suggested fix.  Thanks.